# rubygems 1.3.6 installation fails

Tags: ruby, rubygems, centos

I have installed ruby 1.9.3 from sources and downloaded rubygems 1.3.6 also source.
looking at the manual I untarred the tarball and typed `ruby setup.rb`
This is what I get as output:

```
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems.rb:206:in `try_activate': undefined method 
`find_by_path' for Gem::Specification:Class (NoMethodError)
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:59:in `rescue in require'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:35:in `require'
        from /root/rubygems-1.3.6/lib/rubygems/config_file.rb:50:in `<class:ConfigFile>'
        from /root/rubygems-1.3.6/lib/rubygems/config_file.rb:28:in `<top (required)>'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
        from /root/rubygems-1.3.6/lib/rubygems/gem_runner.rb:8:in `<top (required)>'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
        from setup.rb:25:in `<main>'
```

This is done on CentOS 5

Comment: The current stable version of Rubygems is 1.8.24, any specific reason you are installing 1.3.6?

Comment: No, I was just following a guide. I will try installing 1.8.24

Comment: OK, seems to fix it. If you want to post this as an answer I will check it solved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The current stable version of Rubygems is 1.8.24, any specific reason you are installing 1.3.6?

Comment: because that is what works with rails 2.  check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11028804/undefined-method-name-for-actionmailerstring