# `add_frozen_gem_path': undefined method `source_index' for Gem:Module (NoMethodError) OR Gem.source_index is deprecated

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, deprecated, ruby-on-rails-2

I am using rails 2.3.11, ruby-1.9.2-p320.
Trying to run script/server but getting this error :-

```
system@admin:~/apps/app_name/trunk$ script/server
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 2.3.11 application starting on http://0.0.0.0:3000
/home/system/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@gemset_name/gems/rails-2.3.11/lib/rails/gem_dependency.rb:21:in `add_frozen_gem_path': undefined method `source_index' for Gem:Module (NoMethodError)
    from /home/system/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@gemset_name/gems/rails-2.3.11/lib/initializer.rb:298:in `add_gem_load_paths'
    from /home/system/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@gemset_name/gems/rails-2.3.11/lib/initializer.rb:132:in `process'
    from /home/system/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@gemset_name/gems/rails-2.3.11/lib/initializer.rb:113:in `run'
    from /home/system/apps/app_name/trunk/config/environment.rb:9:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/system/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:126:in `require'
    from /home/system/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:126:in `require'
    from /home/system/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@gemset_name/gems/activesupport-2.3.11/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:182:in `block in require'
    from /home/system/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@gemset_name/gems/activesupport-2.3.11/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:547:in `new_constants_in'
    from /home/system/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@gemset_name/gems/activesupport-2.3.11/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:182:in `require'
    from /home/system/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@gemset_name/gems/rails-2.3.11/lib/commands/server.rb:84:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/system/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:73:in `require'
    from /home/system/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:73:in `require'
    from script/server:3:in `<main>'
```

Then I refered to a few answers on SO and ran following command from terminal :-

```
system@admin:~/apps/app_name/trunk$ gem update --system 1.8.25
```

Now am getting the error :-

```
system@admin:~/apps/app_name/trunk$ script/server
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 2.3.11 application starting on http://0.0.0.0:3000
NOTE: Gem.source_index is deprecated, use Specification. It will be removed on or after 2011-11-01.
Gem.source_index called from /home/system/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@gemset_name/gems/rails-2.3.11/lib/rails/gem_dependency.rb:21.
NOTE: Gem::SourceIndex#refresh! is deprecated with no replacement. It will be removed on or after 2011-11-01.
Gem::SourceIndex#refresh! called from /home/system/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@gemset_name/gems/rails-2.3.11/lib/rails/vendor_gem_source_index.rb:34.
NOTE: Gem::SourceIndex#load_gems_in is deprecated with no replacement. It will be removed on or after 2011-11-01.
Gem::SourceIndex#load_gems_in called from /home/system/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/source_index.rb:322.
NOTE: Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec is deprecated, use Specification.add_spec. It will be removed on or after 2011-11-01.
Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec called from /home/system/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/source_index.rb:127.
NOTE: Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec is deprecated, use Specification.add_spec. It will be removed on or after 2011-11-01.
Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec called from /home/system/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/source_index.rb:127.
NOTE: Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec is deprecated, use Specification.add_spec. It will be removed on or after 2011-11-01.
Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec called from /home/system/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/source_index.rb:127.
NOTE: Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec is deprecated, use Specification.add_spec. It will be removed on or after 2011-11-01.
Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec called from /home/system/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/source_index.rb:127.
NOTE: Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec is deprecated, use Specification.add_spec. It will be removed on or after 2011-11-01.
Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec called from /home/system/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/source_index.rb:127.
NOTE: Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec is deprecated, use Specification.add_spec. It will be removed on or after 2011-11-01.
Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec called from /home/system/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/source_index.rb:127.
NOTE: Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec is deprecated, use Specification.add_spec. It will be removed on or after 2011-11-01.
Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec called from /home/system/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/source_index.rb:127.
NOTE: Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec is deprecated, use Specification.add_spec. It will be removed on or after 2011-11-01.
Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec called from /home/system/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/source_index.rb:127.
NOTE: Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec is deprecated, use Specification.add_spec. It will be removed on or after 2011-11-01.
Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec called from /home/system/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/source_index.rb:127.
NOTE: Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec is deprecated, use Specification.add_spec. It will be removed on or after 2011-11-01.
Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec called from /home/system/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/source_index.rb:127.
NOTE: Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec is deprecated, use Specification.add_spec. It will be removed on or after 2011-11-01.
Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec called from /home/system/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/source_index.rb:127.
NOTE: Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec is deprecated, use Specification.add_spec. It will be removed on or after 2011-11-01.
Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec called from /home/system/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/source_index.rb:127.
NOTE: Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec is deprecated, use Specification.add_spec. It will be removed on or after 2011-11-01.
Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec called from /home/system/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/source_index.rb:127.
NOTE: Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec is deprecated, use Specification.add_spec. It will be removed on or after 2011-11-01.
Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec called from /home/system/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/source_index.rb:127.
NOTE: Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec is deprecated, use Specification.add_spec. It will be removed on or after 2011-11-01.
Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec called from /home/system/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/source_index.rb:127.
NOTE: Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec is deprecated, use Specification.add_spec. It will be removed on or after 2011-11-01.
Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec called from /home/system/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/source_index.rb:127.
NOTE: Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec is deprecated, use Specification.add_spec. It will be removed on or after 2011-11-01.
Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec called from /home/system/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/source_index.rb:127.
NOTE: Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec is deprecated, use Specification.add_spec. It will be removed on or after 2011-11-01.
Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec called from /home/system/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/source_index.rb:127.
NOTE: Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec is deprecated, use Specification.add_spec. It will be removed on or after 2011-11-01.
Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec called from /home/system/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/source_index.rb:127.
NOTE: Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec is deprecated, use Specification.add_spec. It will be removed on or after 2011-11-01.
Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec called from /home/system/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/source_index.rb:127.
NOTE: Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec is deprecated, use Specification.add_spec. It will be removed on or after 2011-11-01.
Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec called from /home/system/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/source_index.rb:127.
NOTE: Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec is deprecated, use Specification.add_spec. It will be removed on or after 2011-11-01.
Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec called from /home/system/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/source_index.rb:127.
NOTE: Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec is deprecated, use Specification.add_spec. It will be removed on or after 2011-11-01.
Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec called from /home/system/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/source_index.rb:127.
NOTE: Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec is deprecated, use Specification.add_spec. It will be removed on or after 2011-11-01.
Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec called from /home/system/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/source_index.rb:127.
NOTE: Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec is deprecated, use Specification.add_spec. It will be removed on or after 2011-11-01.
Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec called from /home/system/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/source_index.rb:127.
NOTE: Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec is deprecated, use Specification.add_spec. It will be removed on or after 2011-11-01.
Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec called from /home/system/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/source_index.rb:127.
NOTE: Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec is deprecated, use Specification.add_spec. It will be removed on or after 2011-11-01.
Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec called from /home/system/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/source_index.rb:127.
NOTE: Gem::SourceIndex#initialize is deprecated with no replacement. It will be removed on or after 2011-11-01.
Gem::SourceIndex#initialize called from /home/system/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@gemset_name/gems/rails-2.3.11/lib/rails/vendor_gem_source_index.rb:100.
/home/system/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@gemset_name/gems/rails-2.3.11/lib/rails/gem_dependency.rb:277:in `==': undefined method `name' for "actionmailer":String (NoMethodError)
    from /home/system/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/dependency.rb:217:in `==='
    from /home/system/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/dependency.rb:217:in `block in matching_specs'
    from /home/system/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/specification.rb:412:in `block in each'
    from /home/system/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/specification.rb:411:in `each'
    from /home/system/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/specification.rb:411:in `each'
    from /home/system/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/dependency.rb:216:in `find_all'
    from /home/system/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/dependency.rb:216:in `matching_specs'
    from /home/system/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/dependency.rb:238:in `to_specs'
    from /home/system/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/dependency.rb:256:in `to_spec'
    from /home/system/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems.rb:1231:in `gem'
    from /home/system/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@gemset_name/gems/rails-2.3.11/lib/rails/gem_dependency.rb:75:in `add_load_paths'
    from /home/system/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@gemset_name/gems/rails-2.3.11/lib/initializer.rb:301:in `block in add_gem_load_paths'
    from /home/system/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@gemset_name/gems/rails-2.3.11/lib/initializer.rb:301:in `each'
    from /home/system/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@gemset_name/gems/rails-2.3.11/lib/initializer.rb:301:in `add_gem_load_paths'
    from /home/system/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@gemset_name/gems/rails-2.3.11/lib/initializer.rb:132:in `process'
    from /home/system/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@gemset_name/gems/rails-2.3.11/lib/initializer.rb:113:in `run'
    from /home/system/apps/app_name/trunk/config/environment.rb:9:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/system/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /home/system/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /home/system/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@gemset_name/gems/activesupport-2.3.11/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:182:in `block in require'
    from /home/system/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@gemset_name/gems/activesupport-2.3.11/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:547:in `new_constants_in'
    from /home/system/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@gemset_name/gems/activesupport-2.3.11/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:182:in `require'
    from /home/system/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@gemset_name/gems/rails-2.3.11/lib/commands/server.rb:84:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/system/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /home/system/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from script/server:3:in `<main>'
```

Following is my environment.rb :-

```
# Be sure to restart your server when you modify this file

# Specifies gem version of Rails to use when vendor/rails is not present
RAILS_GEM_VERSION = '2.3.11' unless defined? RAILS_GEM_VERSION

# Bootstrap the Rails environment, frameworks, and default configuration
require File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), 'boot')

Rails::Initializer.run do |config|

  config.gem 'jrails'

  # Settings in config/environments/* take precedence over those specified here.
  # Application configuration should go into files in config/initializers
  # -- all .rb files in that directory are automatically loaded.

  # Add additional load paths for your own custom dirs
  # config.autoload_paths += %W( #{RAILS_ROOT}/extras )

  # Specify gems that this application depends on and have them installed with rake gems:install
  # config.gem "bj"
  # config.gem "hpricot", :version => '0.6', :source => "http://code.whytheluckystiff.net"
  # config.gem "sqlite3-ruby", :lib => "sqlite3"
  # config.gem "aws-s3", :lib => "aws/s3"

  # Only load the plugins named here, in the order given (default is alphabetical).
  # :all can be used as a placeholder for all plugins not explicitly named
  # config.plugins = [ :exception_notification, :ssl_requirement, :all ]

  # Skip frameworks you're not going to use. To use Rails without a database,
  # you must remove the Active Record framework.
  # config.frameworks -= [ :active_record, :active_resource, :action_mailer ]

  # Activate observers that should always be running
  # config.active_record.observers = :cacher, :garbage_collector, :forum_observer

  # Set Time.zone default to the specified zone and make Active Record auto-convert to this zone.
  # Run "rake -D time" for a list of tasks for finding time zone names.
  config.time_zone = 'UTC'

  # The default locale is :en and all translations from config/locales/*.rb,yml are auto loaded.
  # config.i18n.load_path += Dir[Rails.root.join('my', 'locales', '*.{rb,yml}')]
  # config.i18n.default_locale = :de
end
```

Following is my rakefile :-

```
# Add your own tasks in files placed in lib/tasks ending in .rake,
# for example lib/tasks/capistrano.rake, and they will automatically be available to Rake.

require(File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), 'config', 'boot'))

require 'rake'
require 'rake/testtask'
require 'rdoc/task'
require 'tasks/rails'
```

Following are the answers that I refered to for the solutions :-

[Uninitialized constant ActiveSupport::Dependencies::Mutex (NameError)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5176782/uninitialized-constant-activesupportdependenciesmutex-nameerror)

[undefined method `name' for "actionmailer":String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11028804/undefined-method-name-for-actionmailerstring)

Please help me in the matter.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ruby 1.9.2 isn't that new, you should use 1.9.3-p448. Rubygems 1.8.25 is very old, and should be used with Ruby 1.8 only AFAIK. You are probably using a very old distro. Try using [rvm](http://rvm.io/) to install the latest Ruby 1.9 and Rubygems. Here's a brief quick-start guide. Refer to the docs in case of troubles.

```
\curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable
rvm install 1.9
rvm use 1.9 --default
rvm rubygems latest --verify-downloads 1
gem install bundler
bundle exec ./script/server
```

Answer (score 10):

I resolved it by the command

```
rvm install rubygems 1.4.2 --force
```

Answer (score 0):

Update mysgl adapter in mysql.yml file to mysql2

```
development:
      adapter: mysql2
      database: app_db
      username: root
      password: root
      host: localhost
```

The install mysql2 adapter

```
gem install activerecord-mysql2-adapter
```

Then, install the missing gems from config/environment.rb:

```
rake gems:install
```

give execute permission to the server file inside you project folder as:

```
chmod u+x ./script/server
```

Start the server:
chmod u+x ./script/server 
    `./script/server start` or `./script/server` or  `exec script/server`