# update_rubygems throws "undefined method `find_by_path' for Gem::Specification:Class (NoMethodError)"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache2, passenger, redmine

I'm using Redmine 1.0.3 and when accessing it I get the following error from Passenger:

> Error message:
>
> undefined method `name' for "actionmailer":String
>
> Exception class:
>
> NoMethodError

The suggested fix (see [undefined method `name' for "actionmailer":String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11028804/undefined-method-name-for-actionmailerstring)) doesn't work:

```
# gem install rubygems-update -v 1.3.5
Successfully installed rubygems-update-1.3.5
1 gem installed
# update_rubygems --version=1.3.5
Installing RubyGems 1.3.5
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems.rb:206:in `try_activate': undefined method `find_by_path' for Gem::Specification:Class (NoMethodError)
        from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:59:in `rescue in require'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:35:in `require'
        from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rubygems-update-1.3.5/lib/rubygems/config_file.rb:34:in `<class:ConfigFile>'
        from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rubygems-update-1.3.5/lib/rubygems/config_file.rb:12:in `<top (required)>'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
        from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rubygems-update-1.3.5/lib/rubygems/gem_runner.rb:8:in `<top (required)>'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
        from setup.rb:25:in `<main>'
```

My Ruby version is 1.9.3, my Rails version is 2.3.5.

Does anyone know how to fix this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Downgrading my Ruby version to 1.8.7 solved this problem.